# Wordpress not updading images on index page after setting browser cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser

I have a Wordpress blog that is mainly build of images. I update it daily with images and recently I tested via the Google Speed Test. It came out a bad result because of the browser cache.

I set up the browser cache in the .htaccess file using  but then and I noticed, after a few days that my blog will not show the latest daily pictures on the index page. I had to refresh the browser 2 - 3 times to make it show it. Imagine that no normal surfer will load your page 2 - 3 times consecutively, just to see if there is new content.

I tried everything, not to set expire to .jpg files or set it to just 1 day but Google Speed Test will not pass my website. With Browser Cache I get 87 /100, without it I get 68 / 100.

Is there any way to make my blog show the latest content and also pass the Browser Cache test in Google Speed Test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After searching a more on the internet I came up with this solution. Wordpress index page is actually a php page that generates an html page so I placed this code on in my .htaccess file

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

<FilesMatch "\.(html|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=21600, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I basically updated my blog once per day so a Cache-Control set to 21600 does the trick.